# Constructores de tipos vs constructores de datos (Haskell)

Tags: haskell

Si se crea un vector de con dos componentes genéricos, como:

```
data Vector a = MakeVector a a
```

(puse `MakeVector` en vez de `Vector` a propósito)

(`Vector a`) es el constructor de tipos mientras que
(`MakeVector`) es el constructor de datos.

si hago

```
:t MakeVector 1 2
MakeVector 1 2 :: Num a => Vector a
```

puedo ver que tiene sentido decir que `MakeVector` es un constructor puesto que obtengo una instancia de tipo (`Vector a`) con `a` de tipo `Num`

pero ¿por qué se llama a (`Vector a`) contructor de tipos?, no puedo hacer nada con (`Vector a`), no puedo construir nada, es el identificador del tipo en si mismo en dependencia del tipo que tenga `a`.

todavía más, personalmente encontraría acertado llamar a `MakeVector` constructor de tipo (dado que obtengo un tipo) en vez de constructor de datos, ¿por qué no lo llaman así?

Gracias.

Comment: No entiendo porqué dices que con `Vector a` no puedes hacer nada. Algunos tipos que puedes construir con él: `Vector Int`, `Vector Double`, `Vector String`,....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tenemos

```
data Vector a = MkVector a a
```

entonces, se dice que `Vector` construye tipos, porque su firma (en la categoría `Hask`) es

```
> :k Vector
Vector :: * -> *
```

es decir, toma un tipo y devuelve un tipo (el *"agujero"* `*` es un tipo). Un constructor de tipos únicamente puede tomar tipos (`*`) y devolver tipos (`*`), mientras que un constructor de valores puede tomar cualquier cosa (`Int`, `String`, ...) y devolver cualquier cosa (`Int`, `String`, ...). **La diferencia entre `*` y `String`, `Int`, `Bool`, ... es la misma diferencia que hay entre `String` y `"cabra"`, `"melón"`, ...**

Por ejemplo, podemos ver cómo

```
> :k Vector Int
Vector Int :: *
```

es ahora un tipo *"final"*, hemos construido un tipo.

Por contra, `MkVector` es una función normal y corriente, veamos

```
> :t MkVector
MkVector :: a -> a -> Vector a
```

que toma dos valores y devuelve otro valor.

Como ves, la currificación puede aplicarse indistintamente a tipos como a funciones, es decir, podemos tener el constructor de tipos

```
data Vector' índice valor = MkVector' [(índice, valor)]
```

con firma

```
> :k Vector'
Vector' :: * -> * -> *
```

y podemos currificarla en el primer argumento para obtener otro constructor de tipos, veamos

```
> :k Vector' String
Vector' String :: * -> *
```

que sigue siendo un constructor de tipos (una función en `Hask`).

Así, `Vector` construye tipos y `MkVector` valores, porque el primero es una función sobre los tipos (la categoría `Hask`) y la segunda una función sobre valores.

En Haskell, los tipos se expanden en tiempo de compilación, perdiéndose cualquier información sobre ellos en el resultado. No obstante, el proceso de compilación puede ser usado para *"ejecutar código"*, por ejemplo [Máquina de Turing en el sistema de tipos](http://www.solveet.com/exercises/Maquina-de-Turing-en-el-sistema-de-tipos/278/solution-1906).

Answer (score 1):

> Pero ¿por qué se llama a `(Vector a)` contructor de tipos?, no puedo hacer nada con `(Vector a)`, no puedo construir nada, es el identificador del tipo en si mismo en dependencia del tipo que tenga `a`.

`Vector a` no es un constructor de tipos, sino `Vector` (sin el parámetro `a`) es el constructor de tipos.

En Haskell podemos decir que hay dos sublenguajes:

- El lenguaje de **expresiones** o **términos**;
- El lenguaje de los **tipos**.

Por ejemplo, en esta definición:

```
map :: (a -> b) -> [a] -> [b]
map _ [] = []
map f (a:as) = f a : map f as
```

...`(a -> b) -> [a] -> [b]` es un tipo y `f a : map f as` es una expresión.  Los constructores de tipo son uno de los "ingredientes" que combinamos para escribir tipos compuestos.  Notemos que en el tipo compuesto `(a -> b) -> [a] -> [b]`, `->` y `[]` son constructores de tipo!  (Los dos con su sintaxis especial—`->` es infijo, por ejemplo.)

También mencionamos los constructores de tipo cuando usamos el sistema de clases.  Usando tu mismo ejemplo:

```
instance Functor Vector where
  fmap f (MakeVector x y) = MakeVector (f x) (f y)
```

La respuesta de josejuan menciona las firmas de los tipos  tales como `Vector :: * -> *` ("kinds" en inglés).  La clase `Functor` aplica a tipos con firma `* -> *`, así que en mi declaración se usa `Vector` y no, digamos, `Vector a`:

```
-- EJEMPLO ERRÓNEO:
instance Functor (Vector a) where ...
```

...ya que `Vector a` tiene la firma `*`, que no es compatible con `Functor`.  Pero esto depende de la firma de la clase—por ejemplo la clase `Monoid` aplica a tipos con firma `*`, así que escribimos:

```
import Data.Monoid

instance Monoid a => Monoid (Vector a) where
  mempty = MakeVector mempty mempty
  MakeVector a b `mappend` MakeVector c d = 
      MakeVector (a `mappend` c) (b `mappend` d)
```